# How it works as cyclic group, somebody do explain it.

Tags: group-theory

For a geometrical realisation of a cyclic group, let $S$ be the circle, in the plane, of radius $1$ , and let $\rho_n$ be a rotation through an angle of $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. Then $\rho_n \in A(S)$ and  $\rho_n$ in $A(S)$ generates a group of order $n$, namely, $\{ e, \rho_n, \rho_n^2,\dots ,\rho_n^{n-1}\}$ . How does it work? Can somebody explain it?

Comment: Let our plane be the complex plane, $\mathbb{C}$, and our circle be the unit circle: $U = \{z~:~|z|=1\}$.  Rotation by an angle of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ then is equivalent to multiplication by $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$.  Take $n=4$ for example.  $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{4}} = i$.  If you take $i$ and continually multiply itself with it you get: $i, i\cdot i, i\cdot i\cdot i, i\cdot i\cdot i\cdot i, \dots$ which simplifies to $i, -1, -i, 1, i, -1, \dots$.  I.e., $i$ generates a group of order 4, namely $\{1, i, -1, -i\}$.

Comment: @jmoravitz thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

What may be tripping you up is that $\rho_n^m$ really means ${add}$ $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ to itself $m$ times, not multiply it. I hope that makes things clearer. Frequently operations which are not 'multiplicative' in the arithmetic sense are still expressed this way. Do you see now how after $n-1$ additions of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ we get back to elements which are in equivalence classes with the elements we've already cycled through?